# how to upload my EnterPrise App(In-House App) to my own web server in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, in-house-distribution

I have followed all the below link steps.
[Enterprise App Distribution Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

[7th step for in-house app distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyAFc.png)

in that above link in step no 7, They mention we need to provide

"App URL. A fully qualified HTTPS URL for the iOS App file."

if we give server link in that field the .ipa file (which is generated using Archieve) will automatically upload to location? or we need to manually upload ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually upload the ipa file to the location that you will be provided in Manifest file.

From your web page you will have to provide a download link, that download link will have a download link path to your manifest file, and manifest file will be containing the link of your ipa file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to upload .ipa file to the webserver?

Comment: But we need to give "HTTPS URL" only in App Url Filed right in 7th step?

Comment: Thats correct. Please accept as correct answer if it helps